# Update shiny table from a file input

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I am trying to create a shiny/flexdashboard in which the table can be refreshed by uploading a new file.

The code below is a simple dashboard with a table (using formattable) that is first loaded with a dataset.
The user can use the file upload widget to upload a new dataset - I would like to understand how to refresh the table once the upload is complete. Should this be done in the `new_df_tbl` event?

The example is self-contained and can be used directly in Rstudio.

````
---
title: "Basic"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)
library(formattable)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r}
df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = rnorm(100)
)
```

```{r}
df_tbl <- reactive({
    df %>% select(x, y) # do some stuff here but for simplicity we do nothing
})
```



Sidebar {.sidebar}
=======================================================================

```{r}
fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv"))

br()

actionButton(inputId = "apply", label = "Apply", icon = icon("play"))
```

```{r}
rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
rv <- df

observeEvent(eventExpr = input$apply, 
  handlerExpr = {
      req(input$file1)
      file <- read_csv(input$file1$datapath)
      rv$data <- file
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```


Main
=======================================================================

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Table

```{r}
renderFormattable({
  formattable(df_tbl())
})
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code.

```
rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
rv$data <- df

observeEvent(eventExpr = input$apply, 
  handlerExpr = {
      req(input$file1)
      file <- read_csv(input$file1$datapath)
      rv$data <- file
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```

And wherever you call your table, use `rv$data`. This should update your table when the user loads a file.